# jquery multiple values

Tags: jquery

I have this script, in html I have select with option values 1,2,3,4,5 and I want to display/hide other object, but I don't want to use separate codes for each value:

```
   $('#x').change(function() {   
       $("#xx")[$(this).val() == "5" ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast"); 
   }).change();
```

What I need is to set more values from val() == "5"  to   val() == "1,2,3,4,5"
but this is not working.

How can I do this?

Comment: Be clearer. What do you want to happen when the value is 1, 2, 3, or 4?

Answer (score 4):

At its most simple you can just use logical or `||` for multiple values:

```
$("#xx")[$(this).val() == "5" || $(this).val() == "4" ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast");
```

But with multiple values this gets very long very quickly. At very least you should store `$(this).val()` to a variable and compare that:

```
var val = $(this).val();
$("#xx")[val == "5" || val == "4" ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast");
```

But again this will get long and unwieldly very quickly. A better option is to store an array of the possible values and check if the `val()` is any of the values in the array:

```
var values = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
var val = $(this).val();
$("#xx")[$.inArray(val,values) != -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all, you are great folks :)

Answer (score 1):

you could split that string so it becomse a array and use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and implement it on browsers that don´t have it (information is on the page I likned to). Or use jquerys [$.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch:

```
$('#x').change(function() {   
      var currVal = $(this).val();

switch(currVal){
case 1:
 //your code
      break;    
case 2:
//your code
      break;
case 3:
//your code
      break;
case 4:
//your code
      break;
case 5:
//your code
      break;
   }
});
```